# Fazer um código que traga valores assim(1K, 1M ou 2G)

Tags: c#

Minha regra é:
Se uma valor estiver na casa dos milhares, eu devo apresentar assim:

> 1564 = 1K
>
> 345.786 = 345K
>
> 2345 = 2K

O mesmo vale para os milhões e etc.
Bem, a dúvida é como pegar somente os valores antes do primeiro ponto e etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso você queira um resultado sem arredondamento você pode usar Regex:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; //não esqueça desse using

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string valor = "1.564"; //valor declarado

        string strRegex = "(\\.*)"; //remove os pontos

        valor = Regex.Replace(valor, strRegex, "");

        strRegex = "(\\,\\d{2})"; //remove a parte decimal

        valor = Regex.Replace(valor, strRegex, "");

        strRegex = "\\b(\\d{1,3})\\d{3}\\b"; //regex para verificar se o numero esta na casa de milhar

        if(Regex.Matches(valor, strRegex).Count > 0){
            valor = Regex.Replace(valor, strRegex, "$1K");
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }
        strRegex = "\\b(\\d{1,3})\\d{6}\\b"; //regex para verificar se o numero esta na casa de milhão
        if(Regex.Matches(valor, strRegex).Count > 0){
            valor = Regex.Replace(valor, strRegex, "$1M");
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }
        strRegex = "\\b(\\d{1,3})\\d{9}\\b"; //etc...
        if(Regex.Matches(valor, strRegex).Count > 0){
            valor = Regex.Replace(valor, strRegex, "$1T");
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }
        strRegex = "\\b(\\d{1,3})\\d{12}\\b";
        if(Regex.Matches(valor, strRegex).Count > 0){
            valor = Regex.Replace(valor, strRegex, "$1Q");
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui está um teste do funcionamento no [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o5jRS6)

Comment: Se o número tiver parte decimal ele monta NK,35 por exemplo. Mas vejo aqui

Comment: vou editar para funcionar do jeito que quer amigo.

Comment: @pnet feito. cheque o dotnetfiddle e veja se o resultado te satisfaz

Answer (score 6):

Algo como:

```
List<string> siglas = new List<string>() {
    "K", // Kilo
    "M", // Mega
    "G", // Giga
    "T", // Tera
    "Y"  // Yota
};

long numero = 102314124; // ou qualquer outro número
string resultado = numero.ToString();       
while (numero > 1000 && siglas.Count > 0) {
    numero /= 1000;
    resultado = numero + siglas[0];
    siglas.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Ao final do laço, a string `resultado` tem o que você quer. Note que o laço termina abruptamente se você ficar sem mais siglas. Você pode adicionar mais siglas, caso deseje.

Comment: Muito bom! Como dica eu diria que o `ToString` está "sobrando" ali, porque a concatenação já converte pra string. Outro detalhe pequeno é que o número `10231204124` não cabe num `int` e que seria melhor inicializar resultado com uma `string` vazia para poder usá-la logo depois :p Se você não se importar eu posso editar xD

Comment: Renan, continua vindo a parte decimal. A regra como disse, seria, se o número for 38890 fiaria 38K, mas a parte de remover o decimal eu vejo aqui.

Comment: @LINQ à vontade :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
public static void Main()
{
    long[] numeros = {
        1, 10, 100,
        1000, 10000, 1000000, 125000, 125900,
        1000000, 1250000, 1258000,
        10000000, 10500000, 100000000, 100100000,
        1000000000
    };

    foreach (var numero in numeros)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FormataNumero(numero));
    }
}

public static string FormataNumero(long numero)
{
    // Certifica-se de que o número tenha no máximo 3 dígitos significativos
    // (nenhum arredondamento pode acontecer)
    var i = (long)Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Max(0, Math.Log10(numero) - 2));
    numero = numero / i * i;

    if (numero >= 1000000000)
    {
        return (numero / 1000000000D).ToString("0.##") + "B";
    }
    if (numero >= 1000000)
    {
        return (numero / 1000000D).ToString("0.##") + "M";
    }
    if (numero >= 1000)
    {
        return (numero / 1000D).ToString("0.##") + "K";
    }

    return numero.ToString("#,0");
}
```

Créditos para [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30181106/3551913)

<sup>[Veja funcionando no dotnetfiddle aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qgloGy)</sup>